# The Odin Project: question about chessboard color

Tags: ruby

I am doing Ruby_chess project on Odin Project
https://www.theodinproject.com/courses/ruby-programming/lessons/ruby-final-project
And i don't know how to make my chess color properly as Mrs.rlmoser99's

[image: Her chess board]

Her code about background:
https://github.com/rlmoser99/ruby_chess/blob/master/lib/displayable.rb

i take the same background color from her code,

but our two chessboards are far too different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered this question for you on The Odin Project's Discord server, but wanted to reply here in case others have a similar problem.

I used the solid unicode symbols for both my black and white pieces, instead of using the solid & the outline symbols. For example, both my kings are `" \u265A "`. One has the font color black and the other has the font color white.

https://github.com/rlmoser99/ruby_chess/blob/master/lib/pieces/king.rb